# How to solve this stylelint issue?

Tags: webstorm, stylelint

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "E:/INSTALL MISHA/stylelint/stylelint-master/bin/stylelint.js" -f json --stdin-filename "..\..\..\..\..\:/Computer science/Web Site/HTML CSS JQuery website codecademy/untitled/style.css"
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\INSTALL MISHA\stylelint\stylelint-master\lib\cli.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am getting the following error when I try to a CSS file in WebStorm. How to remove the error?

[image: Stylelint Error]

Comment: may be related to having conflicting dependencies... Does the same command work in terminal? BTW, your stylelint package path looks a bit unusual - no `node_modules`? what do your stylelint preferences (**File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Stylesheets | Stylelint**) look like?

Comment: It is says that the node interpreter is 8.10.0 and located in                    C/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe. The stylelint version is 9.2.0 and I am using WebStorm 2018.1

Comment: @lena The error might be in node modules, since I installed installed node.js for the the sole purpose of running stylelint and other linters. Not  for my personal use.

Comment: @lena I have updated my answer.

Comment: how did you install stylelint? `stylelint/stylelint-master/bin/stylelint.js` doesn't look like  usual stylelint package dir

Comment: @lena Probably through GitHub. But I think the real issue is that npm is not working.